# Progressdialog stuck using couchbase

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchapp

I am using the replication service from [couchbase](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) in one of my project.
I would like to show the replication progress using a Progressdialog with percentage.
As the documentation says I am doing this in an `AsyncTask` so

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
//other code

    double total = push.getCompletedChangesCount() + pull.getCompletedChangesCount();
    progressDialog.setMax(total);
    progressDialog.setProgress(push.getChangesCount() + pull.getChangesCount());

//.....end }
```

On log cat I get

> I/LoginActivity: Replication Progress = 51029 <-this number changes
>   I/LoginActivity: Replication total = 56117 <-this number changes as
>   well

The problem I have is that the progressdialog is stuck in 0%, no progress is showed.
Any idea about how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground` is executed only once , so you cannot get any updates on your dialog.

Use AsyncTask's  `onProgressUpdate` method instead:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    double total = push.getCompletedChangesCount() + pull.getCompletedChangesCount();
    progressDialog.setMax(total);
    progressDialog.setProgress(push.getChangesCount() + pull.getChangesCount());
}
```